# How could I overwrite file hosts in OS X?

Tags: macos, networking, bash, automation

Well, in my company I have to change file hosts to map the domain to the LAN IP because our servers located here. Then when I arrive to home, I have to change hosts file again to comment out which IP I used at company.

I write this bash function to overwrite my `/etc/hosts` but no luck...

```
# Change host file function
chosts() {
   [ "$1" == "-h" ] && sudo cp ~/.local/hosts/hosts.home /etc/hosts
   [ "$1" == "-c" ] && sudo cp ~/.local/hosts/hosts.com /etc/hosts
}
```

I want to know why I can't copy or move my file to `/etc/hosts` and I also need a solution to do this trick.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: +1, what's the error though?

Comment: @Louis: No error, nothing happens just can't overwrite it. After I executed the function, then check hosts file, no changes made to it.

Comment: Okay, but If something gets logged ('console.app' is good for checking), your answer might be in a clue left there.

Comment: not really my forte, but isn't etc/hosts a symlink to private/etc/hosts ? I heard editing that directly gets better results.

Comment: @Tetsujin: Could you describe more about that?

Comment: It's above my pay grade really [I tend to do it the Dummies way, TextEdit or GasMask] but there was a whole lot of mumbling about it on [MacRumours](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=1741422) if that might help you.

Comment: @Tetsujin: Wow, you are the saint. Thank you so much !!!

Comment: Welcome;-) If you find a definitive answer, post it as such & mark it correct, for future searchers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this function to overwrite hosts files!

```
chosts() {
   [ "$1" == "-h" ] && sudo cp ~/.local/hosts/hosts.home /private/etc/hosts
   [ "$1" == "-c" ] && sudo cp ~/.local/hosts/hosts.com /private/etc/hosts
}
```

### Small notice

Remember to keep *hosts.home* and *hosts.com* with permission ***root:wheel***

Comment: Glad you got it. Mark the answer as correct - then it scores better in future searches.